# SWT - Getting the current Date and appending in to a String

Tags: java, date, swt

I am allowing the user to rename a system generated filename.  One of the options is to append the current date and time to the filename.  I have searched on how to get the current data-time with no luck.  I did see a SWT widget DateTime.  But did not understand if you have to build the value from the different calls.

Example

```
DateTime month = datetime.getMonth();
DateTime day = datetime.getDay();

etc.....

String date = (month + "." + day + etc.....);
```

I am basically just wanting to have a method getCurrentDate() that returns a String formatted like mm.dd.yy.hr.mn

Comment: Use Calendar.getInstance(), and format the date and time as you wish with SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can use it as follows:

```
public String getCurrentDate()
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yy.HH.mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    String date = dateFormat.format(date);
    return date;
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) is the Oracle tutorial for date formats.

However, to achieve better sorting results, you should use:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm");
```